# Delay is not working after 1 hour

Tags: java, android, handler

I am using a hanfler within the service to call a method after a delay in android. Its not working for long delays but the same code works for small delay.

```
Handler mHandler; 
Runnable runnable; 

mHandler = new Handler(); 
runnable=new Runnable() { 
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        Log.i("START SERVICE", "START SERVICE:3 Call to Check Status is called"); 
        callToCheckStatus(); 
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000*60*60); 
    } 
};
mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000*60*60);
```

On some blogs i find that when device goes deep sleep then it does not work. SO whats the right way to call a method within in Android.

Comment: Take a look at `AlarmManager`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE.. Thanks .But it did not look useful. I have read this but I am already using Boot Receiver and i can not schedule it from any activity. I need to start a service and then call a method after 60 min.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
public static void intertiAdsStartTimer(Context cnxt) {
    timer = new Timer();
    initializeTimerTask(cnxt);
    //timer.schedule(timerTask, delayTime, repeatedTime);
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, Integer.parseInt("7") * 60 * 1000); //
}

public static void initializeTimerTask(final Context cnxt) {
    try {
        final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            //call your method
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

OR

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something after 10s = 10000ms

    }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Is it not same as mine? Actually when device go into deep sleep state then runnable vanishes. that's the issue.